# Laravel Models with a single table database

Tags: laravel

I am creating a project that fetches data from an XML feed into a single MySQL table. It is a big table (1M+ rows) with the following fields:

- id
- created_at
- updated_at
- last_seen
- seller_id
- product_link
- seller
- seller_category
- name
- price
- image
- description

All the tutorials and documentation that I find around seem to refer to multiple-related tables, which is not my case.

What models should I create having in mind that the following searches will be done:

SELECT name,price,image,description FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%whatever%'

SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE seller_category LIKE '%one_category%' OR seller_category LIKE '%other_category%'

I have read that I should create a Class with a public static function that would extend DB::, however i'm lost with that.

Thank you very much in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to have all the data in a single table?

Comment: How many models will you have pointed at that table?

Comment: do note that when you are running a `LIKE` operator with a prefixed wildcard, you will run a full table scan. For 1M+ rows that will hurt performance

Comment: @lukasgeiter I'm not very fluent in programming, nor SQL databases, i found that all the data was at the same level. What would be a better approach for only this info?

Comment: @Ortix92 Yes i'm aware of that. I already set up an additional index for seller_id, and would probably set up more if needed, right now, select name, price from table where name like '%whatever%' is taking 0.59 secs. While it is not a lot, it is not usable for a web app.

Comment: @Javier I'd create a table for every model you want (maybe even more but I can't tell without knowing everything about the application). Even if they all just have one-to-one relationships. It's still a lot cleaner with multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an eloquent model as per usual and then you can run something like:

`YourModel::where('name','LIKE','%whatever%');`

Nothing fancy really.

The model:

```
<?php

class YourModel extends \Eloquent
{

    protected $fillable = []; // all your fillable fields


}
```

Comment: Hi Ortix

I have created 'app/models/Articulo.php'
<?php

class Articulos extends Eloquent
{
        protected $table = 'tablename';
        protected $fillable = array ('name','seller','seller_category');
}


I have also created  under app/routes.php


Route::get('/iphone6', function()
{
        $search=Articulos::where('name','LIKE','Apple iPhone 6%');
        foreach ($search as $id => $result)
        {
                echo "$id\n";
        }
});


However, If I open a browser and point to http://localhost:8000/iphone6 I just get an HTTP 200 response with no content.

Comment: Damn this comment form is going to kill me. Please see http://pastebin.com/bSMkrfwn for formatted text